# Was Jesus thirsty at the end of the 40 days fast in the wilderness?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 4:

> 1 Then Jesus was led by the Spirit into the wilderness to be tempted by the devil. 2After fasting forty days and forty nights, he was **hungry**. 3The tempter came to him and said, “If you are the Son of God, tell these stones to become bread.”
>
> 4 Jesus answered, “It is written: ‘Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.’

Was Jesus thirsty? What's the significance that there is no mention of the devil tempting him with water?

Comment: The text only states 'fasting' and 'hunger'. You are asking about something that is absent from the text. Thus it is a matter of opinion why it is not there, since it is not mentioned.

Comment: Isn't what you have just stated a matter of opinion? :)

Comment: I have stated facts. Your _opinion_ is that these _facts_ are my opinion.

Comment: Is a question an opinion? :)

Comment: By stating 'significance' you are asserting that there is one. But you are asserting that something which is not there . . . .  is significant. Which becomes, in academic terms - an opinion. It may be that your instinct is a spiritual one and that the Spirit has intended that absence to mean something. But until you demonstrate that spiritual reality (or until someone answers and does that for you) it remains - an opinion.

Comment: P.S. I have cancelled the down-vote with my own up-vote in the hope that this leads somewhere.

Comment: God bless you, brother :)

Comment: And you, brother. This shows the limitations of any public and academic examination of scripture. There are spiritual limitations, but we can get around them : )

Comment: I've always wondered about this.  It's possible he drank water every day, but also possible that, being the Son of God, God gave him the ability to go 40 days without water.  Why we aren't explicitly told seems a mystery, but maybe the answer is intended to be self-evident.  When we fast, should we go without water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the hunger strikes in Ireland in 1980 and 1981 showed, a person can last for about 60 days without food.

However, in the desert, one can last for only a few days (depending on physical activity) without water.  Further, while death might take a few days in hot conditions, unconsciousness would ensue within a days or so in hot conditions.

Thus, the fast of 40 days by Jesus in the desert must have included water, else He could not have survived the 40 days.

Therefore, thirst was not an issue during this time of Jesus' fasting in the desert - He only lacked food as the verb νηστεύω implies.

**Special Case for Ex 34:28**

The fact that Moses went for 40 days and 40 nights with either food or water while in the mountain with God cannot be taken as as evidence that people can survive that long.  Moses had to climb the mountain and return with heavy tablets of stone - a considerable physical exertion.

However, as is well-known, a human cannot survive much more than a day or two with out water - Moses was obviously miraculously sustained by God while in the mountain for 40 days with even water.

Comment: If we consider the conditions of Exodus 34:28 when Moses fasted forty days without bread or water. - Could Jesus not survive Matthew 4:2 without water?

Comment: @חִידָה - good point - I regard that as miraculous because Moses was in the direct presence of the Almighty.

Comment: Researched [Guinness World Records] to discover Andreas Mihavecz lasted 18-days without food or water.

Comment: @חִידָה - thanks for that.  I assume he was unconscious bell before 18 days had passed.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the conditions of Exodus 34:28 when Moses fasted forty days without bread or water. - **Could Jesus survive Matthew 4:2 without water?**

- Yes. Although (unlike Moses & Jesus) the extra-biblical text [Guinness World Records] claims longest fast without food or water by a human (Andreas Mihavecz) is eighteen days.

**Was Jesus 'thirsty' in Matthew 4:2?**

- Yes. - **The Blessed always "ἐπείνασεν" (hunger) and "διψῶντες" (thirst)** stated in Matthew 5:6, referencing [Psalm 63:1-2] "When he was in the desert of Judah" (בִּ֜הְיוֹת֗וֹ בְּמִדְבַּ֥ר יְהוּדָֽה) "O God, You are my God, I seek You. **My soul thirsts for You** ; my flesh longs for You, in an arid and thirsty land, without water." (אֱלֹהִ֚ים | אֵלִ֥י אַתָּ֗ה אֲשַֽׁחֲ֫רֶ֥ךָּ צָֽמְאָ֬ה לְךָ֨ | נַפְשִׁ֗י כָּמַ֣הּ לְךָ֣ בְשָׂרִ֑י בְּאֶֽרֶץ־צִיָּ֖ה וְעָיֵ֣ף בְּלִי־מָֽיִם)

Comment: That is pushing it: the sermon on the mount and the beatitudes came some time after the temptation in the wilderness

Comment: I once fasted for 26 days with nothing but water.  It was a life changing nightmare.